# Producer/Consumer in C with pthread semaphores and multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, producer-consumer

Lets say I have a buffer that has 3 producer threads and 5 consumer threads inserting and consuming to/from the buffer.

I only want to allow 1 producer or up to 3 consumer threads access the buffer at any given time.

Up to 3 consumers can peek at the top element in the buffer, only, if no producer is accessing it.  If more than 1 consumer thread does access the buffer, the last thread to leave must delete the top element.

Now this is *part* of a class assignment, and the assignment explicitly states to use semaphores.  However, I can't think of a way to really implement this wording exactly using only semaphores.

The pseudo code -I think- should look like this: (I'm not worrying about an empty or full buffer, just this sub-part of the problem)

```
sem_init(&binary, 0, 1);  //Init binary semaphore to 1
sem_init(&consumerCount, 0 , 3);  //Allows 3 consumers to access

producer()
{
    createItem()
    sem_wait(&binary)
    appendItem()
    sem_post(&binary)
}

//The above assures nothing else can access buffer while appending an item

consumer()
{

    while( binary unlocked)
    {
        sem_wait(&binary) and sem_wait(&consumerCount)  //Locks the producers out
                                                        //Allows 3 consumers in 
        peek()  //Gets copy of top item
        if( last consumer out )
        {
            delete()  //Deletes top item
            sem_post(&binary)  //Allow producer access back since last one out
        }
        sem_post(&consumerCount)         

    }
}
```

I think that's the gist of the logic, problem is how to implement this with just semaphores.  How do I allow only 1 producer in with a semaphore but allow 3 consumers in on the other side?  It seems like I would need to use something besides a semaphore.

Also, please correct any of the logic if needed, this is meant to just be a general idea.

Comment: SO is not a site for code review or opinions. Do you have a concrete technical question?

Comment: do you want all the consumer get a copy of the data ??

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: So basically you want me to delete this post, then post my real code and say, "How do I let three consumers in with only semaphores?"  Seems stupid when this is a simplified version of the question I'd be asking.                                                 const:  All consumers?  Only the 3 that come in at any given time, but yes they all should be getting a copy.

Comment: With some implementations of _semaphores_, several _permits_ can be _acquired_ in one operation. See for example [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquireUninterruptibly(int)) in Java. Is this also possible with your _semaphores_?

Comment: @nosid: I'm using pthreads...I should have stipulated that.  As far as I know, no.  But, I've only been reading about them for a short period of time.  It seems like some type of signalling would be needed here.   Basically I think the problem stems to: Is there a way to only signal, in pthreads, that a semaphore is not locked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the problem with two semaphores. The first semaphore is used for exclusive access by producers. The second semaphore is used for the *shared* access. The producer tries to acquire all three permits in order to lock out the consumers.

```
sem_init(&exclusive, 0, 1);
sem_init(&shared, 0, 3);

void producer()
{
    sem_wait(&exclusive);
    sem_wait(&shared);
    sem_wait(&shared);
    sem_wait(&shared);
    // critical section
    sem_post(&shared);
    sem_post(&shared);
    sem_post(&shared);
    sem_post(&exclusive);
}

void consumer()
{
    sem_wait(&shared);
    // critical section
    sem_post(&shared);
}
```

Comment: I thought of this and then immediately dismissed it for some reason.  I thought that a producer could get stuck in the waits.  Could three separate producer threads trigger the 1st sem_wait()?  Then they would all be stuck with no way to get out.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For some reason I thought there would only be one producer. I will fix it in a minute.

Comment: Yes, this is what I just implemented.  Your previous post led me right here.  Exactly the answer and I dismissed it early on.  I think this might be "unfair" for the producers because they must wait for 3 locks, where a consumer only needs 1.  Thank you.